# Partially hidden workspace indicator in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: workspaces, 17.10, gnome-shell

Since upgrading to Ubuntu 17.10 the workspace indicator in gnome shell is only partially visible on the right until I hover over it then it expands.

This is annoying because it is very unnecessary and obscures the view of what is open and where it is open. Since this is the whole point of this indicator I am wondering.

Can this be fixed to be fully visible immediately when you hit the windows key or hot corner like it was in Ubuntu GNOME 17.04?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same complain, thankfully there is an easy fix to this problem, just install this gnome extension 
[Always Zoom Workspaces](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/503/always-zoom-workspaces/)

Answer (score 0):

You may try a [GNOME shell extension](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions) called [Expand Workspaces Switcher](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1351/show-workspaces/).

> This is an extension for GNOME Shell 3.26+ that expands the Workspace switcher in the Overview when workspaces are in use, as in previous versions of GNOME Shell.
>
> When this extension is enabled, the workspace switcher will be expanded when you have set a fixed number of workspaces, or are using more than one of the dynamic workspaces.