# How to unhide Workspace container in Activities Overview with terminal commands?

Tags: command-line, 18.04, gnome-shell, workspaces, activities-overview

After pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>, the Activities Overview screen appears. In this Activities Overview screen, a Workspace container that is at the right side of the screen always appears hidden and it will appear only when the mouse pointer moves over the Workspace container. I find such a configuration unproductive. How do I unhide this Workspace container so that it will always appear whenever the Activities Overview Screen appears?

Comment: Not aware of any command-line solutions, but, as always, there are extensions: https://askubuntu.com/q/966805/480481

Comment: @pomsky Thanks. I found that extension [always-zoom-workspaces](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/503/always-zoom-workspaces/) works with Ubuntu 18.04 immediately after it is enabled.

Comment: @pomsky This extension and the other extension that you had referred to in your answer to the link you gave both had `imports.ui.main` in their `extension.js` file. Can u tell me where is this `ui` module found in Ubuntu 18.04?  Is there a python equivalent to this json `ui` module?